# How can I make my system HL7 certified?

Tags: hl7

I'm developing a Health Care System, and I'm new with HL7. My Question is how can I make my system HL7 (Health level 7) certified? What are the main steps I should follow?

Thanks,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about certification requirements

Comment: Just use Google for **HL7 certification** and **HL7 conformance**

Answer (score 2):

You can become member of http://www.hl7.org community and ask there. As far as I know and what http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HL7 says about certifications there is no such thing as 1 worldwide HL7 certification authority right now (although hl7.org offers some kind of [conformance testing](http://www.hl7.org/implement/conformanceTesting.cfm)).

There are many conformance levels and many integration profiles and many vendors and many legacy systems.

What seems to make most sense is to clearly declare **IHE Integration Statement** (see http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks for more) as HL7 and DICOM are rather technical tools, implementation details that nobody really much cares about (besides programmers).

> **Integrating the Healthcare Enterprise (IHE)**
>   ...Systems developed in accordance with IHE communicate with one another better, are easier to implement, and enable care providers to use information more effectively...

Also the Googling tip by @sqlab may be very usefull. By looking for `HL7 Conformance Statement`, `DICOM Conformance Statement`, `IHE Integration Statement` you can find many examples of what other vendors do