# IHE and HL7. PCD-01 ACK

Tags: android, tcp, standards, hl7

I'm trying to get data from a monitor to an Android application and I've took the IHE - PCD-01 transaction as a model.

The scheme is simple, is based on achieve the interconnection between the monitor and the tablet, where the monitor sends constantly information and the application is listening.

But what I don't understand is if I need an ACK or not after every message. Does anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** yes, nothing special here, support the usual HL7 ACK/NACK driven by MSH-15, MSH-16 fields.
 ACK-ing everything by default is "better safe then sorry"

---

The document "IHE Patient Care Device (PCD), Technical Framework, Volume 2 (PCD TF-2) Transactions, Revision 1.0 - Final Text, August 12, 2011" available at http://www.ihe.net/technical_framework/upload/ihe_pcd_tf_vol2_ft_2011-08-12.pdf says

> ..The common static definition of the HL7 acknowledgement (ACK) message is described in Appendix G, "HL7 Implementation Notes"..

which says

> G.1 Network Guidelines
>
> The **HL7 2.6** standard does not define a network communications protocol. Beginning with HL7 2.2, the definitions of lower layer protocols were moved to the Implementation Guide, but are not HL7 requirements. The IHE Framework makes these recommendations:
>
> 1. Applications shall use the Minimal Lower Layer Protocol defined in Appendix C of the HL7 Implementation Guide.
> 2. An application that wants to send a message (initiate a transaction) will initiate a network connection to start the transaction. The receiver application will respond with an acknowledgement or response to query but will not initiate new transactions on this network connection
>
> G.1.1 Acknowledgment Modes
>
> ACKNOWLEDGMENT MESSAGES
>
> Acknowledgment messages may be defined **on an application basis**. However the simple **general acknowledgment message (ACK)** may be used **where the application does not define** a special message (application level acknowledgment) and in other cases as described in Section 2.9, "Message Processing Rules".
>
> The IHE PCD transaction PCD-03 supports „enhanced mode‟ acknowledgements. See discussion under PCD-03 Transactions as well as in B.1 MSH – Message Header Segment and B.2 MSA – Message Acknowledgement Segment

and document "Health Level Seven, Version 2.6 © 2007, Chapter 2: Control" coming from the "HL7 Messaging Standard Version 2.6" package which can be downloaded from http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185 describes the accept and validate behavior in

> 2.9.2 Message response using the original processing rules
>
> ..too long to quote..
>
> 2.9.3 Response using enhanced acknowledgement
>
> ..too long to quote..

depending on the values of `MSH-15 Accept Acknowledgement Type` and `MSH-16 Application Acknowledgment Type` fields in the HL7 message

The above chapters from the HL7 standard contain what you want to read and implement/support.

**EDIT:**

Simply put, in HL7 protocol in every message sent the sender may request an `ACK` receipt by flagging appropriate fields in the message header segment. IHE does not remove this rule and does not enforce any other but enables any other convention to be defined **on an application basis**. Correct expected behavior is defined by the HL7 specification and in order to get it right and create a conforming implementation (without hidden surprises for your 3rd parties) you may need to read it several times (see also [Stack Overflow: How can I make my system HL7 certified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391653/how-can-i-make-my-system-hl7-certified))

For example this is how [HAPI](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/) library handles the ACKing, snippet comes from http://sourceforge.net/p/hl7api/code/764/tree/tags/Root_REL_1_2/hapi-mvn/hapi-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/hl7v2/protocol/impl/ProcessorImpl.java

```
/** 
 * @see ca.uhn.hl7v2.protocol.Processor#cycle(boolean)
 */
public void cycle(boolean expectingAck) throws HL7Exception {
    log.debug("In cycle({})", expectingAck);

    cleanReservations();
    cleanAcceptAcks();
    cleanReservedMessages();

    Transportable in = null;
    try {
        if (expectingAck) {
            in = tryReceive(myContext.getLocallyDrivenTransportLayer());
        } else {
            in = tryReceive(myContext.getRemotelyDrivenTransportLayer());
        }
    } catch (TransportException e) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        throw e;
    }
    
    // log
    if (in != null) {
           log.debug("Received message: {}", in.getMessage());
    } else {
      log.debug("Received no message");
    }
    
    // If we have a message, handle it
    if (in != null) { 
        String acceptAckNeeded = null;
        // String appAckNeeded = null;
        String ackCode = null;
        String ackId = null;
        
        try {
            String[] fieldPaths = {"MSH-15", "MSH-16", "MSA-1", "MSA-2"};
            String[] fields = PreParser.getFields(in.getMessage(), fieldPaths);         
            acceptAckNeeded = fields[0];
            // appAckNeeded = fields[1];
            ackCode = fields[2];
            ackId = fields[3];
        } catch (HL7Exception e) {
            log.warn("Failed to parse accept ack fields in incoming message", e);
        }
        
        if (ackId != null && ackCode != null && ackCode.startsWith("C")) {
            long expiryTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60;
            myAcceptAcks.put(ackId, new ExpiringTransportable(in, expiryTime));
        } else {
            AcceptAcknowledger.AcceptACK ack = AcceptAcknowledger.validate(getContext(), in);
        
            if ((acceptAckNeeded != null && acceptAckNeeded.equals(AL)) 
                || (acceptAckNeeded != null && acceptAckNeeded.equals(ER) && !ack.isAcceptable()) 
                || (acceptAckNeeded != null && acceptAckNeeded.equals(SU) && ack.isAcceptable())) {
                trySend(myContext.getRemotelyDrivenTransportLayer(), ack.getMessage());    
            }

            if (ack.isAcceptable()) {
                if (isReserved(ackId)) {
                
                    log.debug("Received expected ACK message with ACK ID: {}", ackId);
                
                    removeReservation(ackId);
                    long expiryTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 5;                
                    myAvailableMessages.put(ackId, new ExpiringTransportable(in, expiryTime));
                    
                } else {

                    log.debug("Sending message to router");
                    Transportable out = myContext.getRouter().processMessage(in);
                    sendAppResponse(out);
                    
                }
            } else {
                // TODO: should we do something more here? Might be nice to 
                // allow a configurable handler for this situation
                log.warn("Incoming message was not acceptable");
            }
            
        }
    } else {
        String transport = expectingAck ? " Locally driven " : "Remotely driven";
        log.debug("{} TransportLayer.receive() returned null.", transport);
    }
    
    sleepIfNeeded();

    log.debug("Exiting cycle()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer :) 
of course that it is better to use an ACK to make sure if the receiver is getting the message but what I wanted to know if it was mandatory or not using the PCD-01 transaction.

I've read your documents and what I've understood is that the use of ACK depends on the MSH-15 and MSH-16 fields content, but with the following information:

> An application that wants to send a message (initiate a transaction) will initiate a network connection to start the transaction. The receiver application will respond with an acknowledgement or response to query but will not initiate new transactions on this network connection

I understand that the ACK is only at the beginning of the connection not after every message, is it right?

Comment: It's best (and normal) to ACK every message, and to resend it after a period of time if you don't get a response. Else the message might be lost. PCD type messages are sometimes sent without acknowledgement messages since no one wants to devote any time to lost messages - they're lost and there will be alarms elsewhere. (I don't know what IHE say about that or not)

Comment: **no**, after every message or after every second message are also allowed scenarios if you (as an application creator) don't specify it otherwise. See my edited answer for some more pointers